# What is the best way for an (almost) complete beginner to learn Digital Painting?

Tags: resource-recommendations, teaching

*If this question has been asked already, I apologise.*

I've had trouble finding a good recommendation of things to learn in order to become a good digital artist. The Internet is full of suggestions, of course, but I'd like to hear some advice from experienced artists, if possible. Is it better to first learn traditional painting and drawing, before getting into digital media? Or is it better to first complete some courses or read some books on Photoshop or Illustrator? 
It's a bit confusing for someone wanting to learn on his own. If someone could shed some light on this matter, it'd be great.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What type of painting are you looking to do?

Comment: The computer is just a tool. The art/talent/creative mind isn't part of the software license.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Everything. I'm fascinated by digital art, and I'd like to learn how to draw myself.

Comment: @xenoid I understand, but what is the best way to achieve that creative mind?

Comment: Its not a question of having a creative mind, its a question of being able to copy what you see.. Then cunstruct things you can not see.

Comment: @joojaa I beg to differ. Any skill or method is learnable, including the capability to copy or invent things. However, you can't learn something advanced without the necessary prerequisites. That's what I'm seeking to learn right now.

Comment: @WordBearer i didn't say the skill can not be learnt, i said creative mind is not a prerequisite, all you need to know is how to copy what you see. Thats where you start. In fact its been demonstrated that everybody can work as a photocopier of what they see.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to paint, you need to learn how to paint.

What tools you use to paint don't matter. The fundamental methods and theories used for painting are the same whether using crayons and construction paper or a mouse and software.

Learning software will *never* teach someone how to be a painter. Software is a tool, that's all. A means to an end. Software can not tell you where to put a brush stroke, or what type of stroke to use or what color works best...

Comment: I understand your point. I didn't find a more appropriate Stack Exchange to ask this question, so I figured this is where I'm most likely to get an answer. What do you think is the best way to learn to paint? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I didn't post anything about this being the "wrong" stack to post your question. How to "learn to paint' is a *very* broad topic. There are classes, books, online courses... etc.