# Resources for digital painting

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, painting

I have no experience in panting and drawing but I would like to start learning it in digital media. Are there any books, websites, or tutorials which teach digital painting and drawing? I use Corel Painter, but I do not want tutorials about how to use the software.

Comment: Digital painting/drawing is merely painting/drawing with different tools - If you aren't seeking how to use software, just get books on painting.. color, light and shadow, depth..... etc.

Comment: Relevant: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8054/recommended-tools-for-digital-art-paintings

Comment: Relevant: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/95445/what-is-the-best-way-for-an-almost-complete-beginner-to-learn-digital-painting

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Corel Painter´s portal? https://learn.corel.com/painting-tutorials/

Or youtube? https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=corel+painter

Answer (score 2):

I'm only going to tackle the online part, here are some of my favorites and I'll probably add to it when I have a bit more time:

- [Ctrl-paint](https://www.ctrlpaint.com/) is a library of free videos which covers both the traditional knowledge and the digital part
- Look for artists who do online streaming to see how they work. If they're live, you might be able to ask a question or two about their process. [Here's a link for Twitch](https://www.twitch.tv/directory/all/tags/02ba4017-ed3b-4b82-ab20-011860784f77?tl=dfaa4f24-e99f-430d-aa29-8fb2b2717ece) but I'm guessing there are others on other services.
- Lynda.com has a few paid courses about [digital painting](https://www.lynda.com/Painter-tutorials/Digital-Painting-Fundamentals/167070-2.html?srchtrk=index%3A3%0Alinktypeid%3A2%0Aq%3Adigital%20painting%0Apage%3A1%0As%3Arelevance%0Asa%3Atrue%0Aproducttypeid%3A2)